# Funciones Javascript que ejecutan parte de otras funciones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, datatables

Tengo una función que me agrega unos detalles a la DataTable, la función me la activa un botón que es agregar, luego oculta la modal. lo que quiero es que el usuario tenga la opción de seguir agregando detalles un botón que agregue los detalles a la tabla, limpie la modal y no la oculte. acá dejo parte de mi código porque es muy extenso.

```js
function agregarDetalle() {
  var detalleCaptura = $('#detalleCaptura');
  var componentes = $('#componentes').val();
  var tiempoColecta = $('#tiempoColecta').val();
  rowNum++;
  var t = detalleCaptura.DataTable();
  t.row.add([
    '<a href="#myModal" id="editRow" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Editar" custom-modal="true" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" onClick="editRow(' + rowNum + ')"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' +
    '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="idEliminarFila' + rowNum + '" title="Eliminar" onClick="deleteRow(' + rowNum + ')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
    '<input type="hidden" id="componentes' + rowNum + '"   name="datosCaptura[add][row' + rowNum + '][componentes]"   value="' + componentes + '" />  <p id="pcomponentes' + rowNum + '">' + componentes + '</p>',
    '<input type="hidden" id="tiempoColecta' + rowNum + '" name="datosCaptura[add][row' + rowNum + '][tiempoColecta]" value="' + tiempoColecta + '" /><p id="ptiempoColecta' + rowNum + '">' + tiempoColecta + '</p>' +
  ]).draw(false);

  $('#myModal').modal("hide");
  return false;

}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="agregarDetalle" data-dismiss="alert" class="btn btn-flat btn-success btn-save-coupon-ref" onClick="agregarDetalle()"><span class="fa fa-save"></span>Agregar</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-success btn-save-coupon-ref" onClick="guardarYcrearNueva()"><span class="fa fa-save"></span>Crear y agregar otro</button>
```

Quisiera que la segunda funcion se ejecute hasta antes del ("modal".hide)

Comment: El código tiene algunos errores (p.e. cadenas inacabadas). Deberías crear un [mcve] en la pregunta para que podamos ver el problema y que sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Bueno, dice que no quieres ocultar el modal, puedes comentar esta línea y ya estaría.  $('#myModal').modal("hide");
Y lo que dices lo podes hacer usando una bandera en la función, me explico en la función agregar detalle recibe una variable, un boolean entonces en el codigo de la funcion preguntas si variable  $('#myModal').modal("hide"); 
En caso contrario no se ejecutaría y listo!

Comment: No logro entender la necesidad concretamente, si logras crear un ejemplo donde podamos ver la funcionalidad completa sería bueno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías pasar un parámetros a la función dependiendo de a que botón le des, y así luego ejecutar el `hide`.

```js
function agregarDetalle(cerrar) {
  var detalleCaptura = $('#detalleCaptura');
  var componentes = $('#componentes').val();
  var tiempoColecta = $('#tiempoColecta').val();
  rowNum++;
  var t = detalleCaptura.DataTable();
  t.row.add([
    '<a href="#myModal" id="editRow" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Editar" custom-modal="true" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" onClick="editRow(' + rowNum + ')"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' +
    '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="idEliminarFila' + rowNum + '" title="Eliminar" onClick="deleteRow(' + rowNum + ')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
    '<input type="hidden" id="componentes' + rowNum + '"   name="datosCaptura[add][row' + rowNum + '][componentes]"   value="' + componentes + '" />  <p id="pcomponentes' + rowNum + '">' + componentes + '</p>',
    '<input type="hidden" id="tiempoColecta' + rowNum + '" name="datosCaptura[add][row' + rowNum + '][tiempoColecta]" value="' + tiempoColecta + '" /><p id="ptiempoColecta' + rowNum + '">' + tiempoColecta + '</p>' +
  ]).draw(false);
  /// Si esto es true, cierra el modal.
  if(cerrar) {
       $('#myModal').modal("hide");
  }
  return false;

}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="agregarDetalle" data-dismiss="alert" class="btn btn-flat btn-success btn-save-coupon-ref" onClick="agregarDetalle(true)"><span class="fa fa-save"></span>Agregar</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-success btn-save-coupon-ref" onClick="agregarDetalle(false)"><span class="fa fa-save"></span>Crear y agregar otro</button>
```

Ambos botones llaman a `agregarDetalle()` y como parametro le pasas `true` o `false`.

Comment: El snippet tiene un error. `"message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got ']'",`